how can i create a div that takes up all available space but does not overflow?
I am trying to build a small admin dashboard for a personal application but i can not figure out how to make sure the page itself can now overflow, but rather the elements inside do.
this is the example code i am trying to get to work:
<body>
  <div class="h-screen w-screen bg-teal-100 flex overflow-hidden">
    <!-- Toolbar with a fixed width -->
    <div class="h-full bg-blue-50" style="width: 100px;">Toolbar</div>

    <!-- Container for Sidebar and Content 1, taking up the remaining width -->
    <div class="flex-grow h-full bg-orange-50 flex">
      <!-- Sidebar with a fixed width -->
      <div class="bg-purple-50" style="width: 200px;">Sidebar</div>

      <!-- Content 1 taking the remaining space -->
      <div class="flex-grow h-full bg-indigo-500 flex flex-col">
        <div class="bg-green-50">A</div>
        <div class="bg-purple-50">B</div>
        <div class="flex-grow bg-teal-200 flex flex-col">
          <div class="bg-green-50">Header</div>

          <!-- Table div with growing and scrolling capability -->
          <div class="flex-grow bg-red-200 overflow-auto">
            <!-- Oversized content to demonstrate scrolling -->
            <div class="w-[200vw] h-[200vh] text-white">
              H (large content here to activate scrolling)
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="bg-purple-50">Footer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

what i am trying to achive is to have a table:
 <div class="w-[200vw] h-[200vh] text-white">
              H (large content here to activate scrolling)
 </div>

where if the table overflows i get scrollbars only for that table. This is driving me insane

In such a realization the scrollable div must have an explicit height specified.
This line
<div class="flex-grow bg-teal-200 flex flex-col">

should be for example
<div class="flex-grow bg-teal-200 flex flex-col h-0">
          

codepen
